# SQL Table Partitioning FileGroup

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I currently use the script below to partition a large table with around one billion rows and over. It will add multiple partitions on the table for each month for 3 or so years.

How can I make it so that each partition is a separate file/filegroup on the disk instead of Primary? i.e. a file called 202001, 202002 (for each year/month).

Is there a benefit of doing this versus keeping it in a single file (default). (Edit: answered below in the comments).

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunction (datetime2) 
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ();

DECLARE @MonthStartDate datetime2 = '20170201';  
WHILE @MonthStartDate < '20200601'  
BEGIN  
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunction()
        SPLIT RANGE(@MonthStartDate);
    SET @MonthStartDate = DATEADD(month, 1, @MonthStartDate);
END;

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME DatePartitionScheme
    AS PARTITION DatePartitionFunction ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);
GO
```

Comment: Setting up the partitions is another matter, but whether or not it's a good idea depends on the following: 1. Will you be querying across partitions often? 2. Do you need to load lots of new data quickly or drop existing data quickly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
1. I will be querying multiple partitions such as comparing April 2017 Vs April 2018 or April 2017 Vs May 2017.
2. Yes, loading lots of data, I will be keeping all data. The files will be on the same NVMe drive but don't know if it will help maintenance if they separated. Thanks.

Comment: The only real advantages of partitioning are in loading new data/dropping old data quick.  Otherwise you can just use the date as the beginning of your clustered index and achieve nearly the same result.

Comment: But does it make a difference if they are in separate filegroup files on the storage medium versus the default single file. I can imagine yes, if each file is on separate storage mediums, but there may be other benefits such as making a filegroup read-only for example.

Comment: This article might help, discusses using multiple filegroups for recovery purposes: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1621/sql-server-partitioned-tables-with-multiple-filegroups-for-high-availability/

Comment: If you're going to leave all of the data on the same disks (or, generally, same *class* of disk), then having different data on different files doesn't get you much. The classic argument was to move older data to cheaper media (i.e. NVMe → SSD → Magnetic media perhaps).

Comment: If for some reason you need to shrink files, it might be better to have multiple file groups, that you can shrink one-by-one. But it depends on your workflow.

Comment: Thanks. I won't ever be deleting anything, as it's all important.